# IdentityServer: client returns 401.1 instead of redirecting

Tags: owin, identityserver3

We have an IdentityServer client using the hybrid flow that is inexplicably not redirecting to the IdentityServer IdP.

What is the right approach to debugging this?

I'm not getting any kind of hard errors, it just returns 401.1 instead of 302.

RedirectToIdentityProvider never gets called.

Comment: You are probably missing the owin.host.systemweb package

Comment: owin.host.systemweb 3.0.1 is installed.

Comment: Client could be configured as passive when it should be active (or vice versa, I forget). This setting determines what happens when a user is not authorised.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the logging for Identity Server: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

If it's not redirecting at all, then it isn't Identity Servers fault, but the setup within your client application.

Comment: Yeah, almost certainly not IS's fault.  Just looking for some advice on debugging this stuff.

Comment: No worries. Next step will be to enable logging for the authentication middleware in your client app (assuming you are using Katana): https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging